# Best way to handle multiple files adding/editing/deleting in web applications from ui point of view?

Tags: language-agnostic, user-interface, wiki

Application platform is WWW.

I have user interface dilema. My user can have many files. File has attributes such as name and description that can be changed by user.

Currently I have users list with edit action when I only allow to edit user data such as name, address, phone etc. on one screen, and files list with links to edit or delete for individual file on another screen.

I think it would be nice to allow user to edit his data and adding/editing/deleting files on one screen, but assuming it's www I also think that:

1. it would be not so easy to develop
2. maybe a little confusing for user, because he can expect that every one-to-many relation that user has can be managed from edit screen

I'm interested in your solutions to similiar problems.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at jQuery datatables: http://www.datatables.net/

They provide a neat and usable way to arrange data (eg. you could use one row per file with columns for editing, deleting etc) that way you have it on the same page as the user's own details (I think that's what you wanted?)

Comment: no, I think about user edit screen (with form to edit) and then on another tab maybe allowing to add new files, edit them, delete them without confusion to user (for example: user changes his name (not clicking save), then went to files tab, add file, site reloads, and wait a minute... my name has changed or not?).

Comment: jquery is capable of updating asynchronously (ie they don't need to refresh the page) and also tabs if that's what you wanted. If you aren't sure what jQuery is, I suggest learning it, it's highly valuable in these situations...

Comment: I know it ;) I'm concern about user experience. Let's assume I use jquery and do 'ajax' upload: user opens editing screen, edits his name, then go to files tab, add new file and then goeas to other screen not clicking save on the form, is file added or not? It shouldn't be, I don't click save, but it is there. I'm simply wondering if one screen idea is worth confusion and all extra work from user point of view. Maybe you have some thoughts on that?

Comment: If you can make the one screen look good and not cluttered, put it on one screen. The ajax issue, why do you need a save button? Just have some feedback when it has been uploaded to let them know. If you wanted the save button, don't execute the ajax query until they press it. Simplicity is key, having multiple pages can confuse people.